# How to reach into iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent, getelementbyid

I would like to know how to have my parent page reach into an iframe and set the `innerhtml` (using jQuery `.html()`) to a variable that I will supply.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('framer');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var content_destination = innerDoc.getElementById('placecontenthere');  
$(content_destination).html("<span class='red'>Hello</span>");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: stil no salvation from there though, even though our questions were in fact similar

Comment: Will, is the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: would someone be able to come up with a js fiddle of this?

Comment: Benjamin Gruenbaum, yes, yes it is. I am aware of the rule you are thinking of

Comment: Will, here http://jsfiddle.net/w9U5J/ put content in iframe

Comment: Where are you running this code? Are you running it after the iframe is ready? `$(document).ready()` won't suffice, because it doesn't guarantee the iframe has **loaded**. You might look into `$(window).on("load", func...`

Answer (score 1):

For accessing iframe contents with jQuery you can use the contents() - function, as described here: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Your code example could be replaced by a oneliner;

```
$('#framer').contents().find('#placecontenthere').html('<span class="red">Hello</span>');
```

Comment: Hi! I have seen that one line of code around a lot of questions like this one. After having tried lots of variations on that, none of them working, I am still stumped.

Comment: okay, then it might be useful to know, what exactly you are displaying inside the iframe. It seems to me that there's something wrong with your markup or that for some reason your browser does not allow access to this particular iframe (maybe because of same origin policy)

Comment: inside the iframe I have a pretty large php document with a lot of CSS, PHP, and Javascript. I was hoping to find a div inside of the iframe and place dynamic content in it.

Comment: also, I dont think i am in violation of the same origin policy. the parent page is a wordpress template, and the iframe src is a page in the same server, nearby in the directory structure and it loads fine enough. Is there a test though? To make sure they are registering as the same?

Comment: Sounds like it's okay. In my opinion there are two possible reasons left: Either #framer or #placecontenthere is not found by the jQuery selector engine. Can you verify that #placecontenthere exists inside your iframe?